# Where is my mistake $\iint_{Q} (x+y)^{2013}dxdy$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm preparing for a calculus exam, and I tried to solve the following question.

$Q$ is square $[-1,1]^2 \subset \mathbb R^2$

We are asked to evaluate $\iint_Q (x+y)^{2013}dxdy$

Here is what I did:

$$\iint_Q (x+y)^{2013}dxdy = \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-1}^{1} (x+y)^{2013}dxdy=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{(x+y)^{2014}}{2014} |_{x=-1}^{1}dy$$

so overall after finishing with $dx$ we have:

$$\frac{1}{2014} \int_{-1}^{1}(y+1)^{2014}-(y-1)^{2014}dy=\frac{(y+1)^{2015}-(y-1)^{2015}}{2015*2014} |_{y=-1}^{1} $$

But note that $$2^{2015}-0^{2015}-0^{2015}+(-2)^{2015}=2^{2015}-2^{2015}=0$$

so the entire double integral is equal to zero.

However, when I check my answer in wolfram alpha, wolfram says that this integral is equal to $9.27057*10^{599}$

I'm just wondering where is my mistake? Or perhaps wolfram alpha gave the wrong answer because of a numerical error.

Comment: As far as I can tell your integration is correct.  No idea what happened with WA.

Comment: It's clear that the second integral is 0 since the intregrand is odd and the interval symmetric around y=0.

Comment: So why is wolfram saying otherwise? Numerical error?

Comment: Numerical error, probably. You might you want to test wolfram with smaller exponents : compute the integral of $(x+y)^{3}$, $(x+y)^5$, $(x+y)^7$ in wolfram and see what happens

Comment: They all yield zero. As expected. I suspect that this integral is zero for any odd exponent. I will close this question now. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used WolframAlpha to evaluate the definite integral over the symmetric interval $[-1,1]$,

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{(y+1)^{2014}-(y-1)^{2014}}{2014}dy,$$

and was given the correct value of zero instead of the anomolous result reported by the OP. On a hunch I asked WA to compute the definite integral over just the nonnegative part $[0,1]$, and sure enough:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(y+1)^{2014}-(y-1)^{2014}}{2014}dy=9.27058\times 10^{599}.$$

The mistake appears to exist between keyboard and chair, not WolframAlpha.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integration%20%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A(x%2By)%5E(2013)%2F%2F%5D%20%5B%2F%2Fmath%3Adx%20dy%2F%2F%5D%20for%20x%20from%20%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A-1%2F%2F%5D%20to%20%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A1%2F%2F%5D%20for%20y%20from%20%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A-1%2F%2F%5D%20to%20%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A1%2F%2F%5D

Comment: @OriaGruber Huh, that's weird.  Perhaps the fact that it gets the single integral I mentioned correct yet your double integral wrong can be used to narrow the source of this bug.

Answer (score 0):

Numerical Error on Wolfram Alpha's side. The integral is zero.